# d3.js proportional symbol map: setting radius of a circle based on data value

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm following this great example of how to make a map using d3.js with mapbox:

https://franksh.com/posts/d3-mapboxgl/

It works great, except I'm wondering how, using this example, one would make the circles proportional symbols, i.e. the radius of the circles will reflect a data value.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = "YOUR_TOKEN";
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
    center: [-74.5, 40.0],
    zoom: 9
  });


  var container = map.getCanvasContainer();
  var svg = d3
      .select(container)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "500")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", 2);

function project(d) {
  return map.project(new mapboxgl.LngLat(d[0], d[1]));
}

#Lat, long, and value
var data = [
  [-74.5, 40.05, 23],
  [-74.45, 40.0, 56],
  [-74.55, 40.0, 1],
  [-74.85, 40.0, 500],
];

var dots = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "#ff0000");

function render() {
  dots
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return project(d).x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return project(d).y;
    });
}

map.on("viewreset", render);
map.on("move", render);
map.on("moveend", render);
render(); // Call once to render

</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

If I set the radius according to the actual data value, some circles are super big and some are super small:

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return d[2]; }) //trying to make radius a function of the actual value
```

Likewise, applying a multiplier doesn't work well (again, some point super big, some super small):

```
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d[2] * 2; })
```

I think what I need to do is map the domain of the data to a range that will signify the radius (i.e. using d3 scale linear), but I'm not totally sure what best practice is here.  I've seen examples using `geoPath.pointRadius(function(d))` but I don't think that applies here since I'm not using a path generator with this particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to use pointRadius, I'd consider it less common and dependingo on use case more cumbersome, but more importantly, it doesn't solve the scaling problem: you still need to specify a radius and your current scaling isn't producing the desired results.

The area of a circle is proportional to the radius squared, which means that a linear scale is not ideal. You've essentially used a simple linear scale in both your attempts, and in both the large circle is 250,000 times larger than the smallest circle.

We could use d3.scaleLinear to create a more restricted range, so that the smallest circle is closer in size to the larger circle:

```js
let scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,500]).range([2,20]);
let data = [1, 10, 100, 250, 500];

let g = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+(i*50+50)+", 50)")
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", scale)
  .attr("fill", "#ccc")
  
g.append("text")
  .text(d=>d)
  .attr("fill","black")
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .attr("dy", -20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

But it still suffers as the value is not proportionate to the values area but the radius. Well, the radius is almost proportionate to value, but since our the lower limit of our range is 2, this isn't true. I've set a minimum value for the radius with the lower bounds of the scale's range to ensure that values close to zero are still visible (otherwise the smallest circle would be invisible essentially as it would have a radius of 1/25 pixels).

Instead, given that circles' areas are proportionate to the radius squared, we could use a square root scale to make the circles area (more) proportionate to their value:

```js
let scale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0,500]).range([2,20]);
let data = [1, 10, 100, 250, 500];

let g = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+(i*50+50)+", 50)")
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", scale)
  .attr("fill", "#ccc")
  
g.append("text")
  .text(d=>d)
  .attr("fill","black")
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .attr("dy", -20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Here we have areas that are much closer to being proportionate to the underlying values (again, since our range doesn't start at 0 this isn't quite true). We could set the lower limit of the range to zero, which would result in much more honest representations of the data in terms of area, however, depending on what you are trying to convey it might be appropriate to leave a minimum radius a bit above zero, if we change it to zero, we essentially lose the smallest value (1):

```js
let scale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0,500]).range([0,20]);
let data = [1, 10, 100, 250, 500];

let g = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+(i*50+50)+", 50)")
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", scale)
  .attr("fill", "#ccc")
  
g.append("text")
  .text(d=>d)
  .attr("fill","black")
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .attr("dy", -20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

We can go one step further and use a scale that finds the third or higher root, which will lose proportionality, but might be useful in showing differences in value for the lower portion of the domain while homogenizing values in the upper portion of the domain:

```js
let scale = d3.scalePow().exponent(.25).domain([0,500]).range([0,20]);
let data = [1, 10, 100, 250, 500];

let g = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate("+(i*50+50)+", 50)")
  
g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", scale)
  .attr("fill", "#ccc")
  
g.append("text")
  .text(d=>d)
  .attr("fill","black")
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .attr("dy", -20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

There are more scales of course, but for circles, generally a square root scale is appropriate, especially with zero as the lower bounds for domain and range as then circles are proportionate to value. However, there are cases of course for using a different scale, non-zero bounds for domain and/or range.

Comment: Thanks man!  Super useful.  The second example worked best for my purposes, and I ended up getting it to work via:  let scale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).range([2,30]) .    Then I called the scale function when setting the radius: .attr("r", function(d) { return scale(d.total)})

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd point out that you can certainly use the Mapbox API directly to lay down points and size them according to data. To do so requires understanding the Mapbox API writing [Mapbox expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/). An advantage (particularly, for large data sets) is that your map will be much more responsive, since Mapbox will use the GPU to handle interaction.

Of course, if you're familiar with D3 and your data is reasonably sized, then it might make perfect sense to lay down the SVG on top of the map and manipulate the points in the SVG with D3. If you're code is set up correctly, you should be able to do something like:

```
svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("r", (d) => d.size)
```

Here's an Observable notebook where both techniques are illustrated: https://observablehq.com/d/fd3634ff22dc033a

Finally, I think it's worth pointing out that, while very cool, the webpage you refer to is a bit old and uses outdated versions of both Mapbox and D3. Mapbox, in particular, has changed quite a bit since then with the move to V2.

Comment: Thanks!   Is it just a matter of updating the src attribute for the mapbox.js link in my code?  I want to use d3.js for this because personally I think d3 points look better than mapbox's.. but if updating mapbox would give a better basemap, then I would like to try that..