# How can I define map extent based on points displayed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have the following map I've made, by overlaying points on a mapbox map using d3.js.

I'm trying to get the map to zoom so that the map extent just includes the d3 markers (points).

I think the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
//find the northernmost, easternmost, southernmost, westernmost points in the data

//get some sort of bounding box?

//make map extent the bounding box?
```

Existing code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = "YOUR_TOKEN";
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
    center: [-74.5, 40.0],
    zoom: 9
  });


  var container = map.getCanvasContainer();
  var svg = d3
      .select(container)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "500")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", 2);

function project(d) {
  return map.project(new mapboxgl.LngLat(d[0], d[1]));
}

#Lat, long, and value
var data = [
  [-74.5, 40.05, 23],
  [-74.45, 40.0, 56],
  [-74.55, 40.0, 1],
  [-74.85, 40.0, 500],
];

var dots = svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "#ff0000");

function render() {
  dots
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return project(d).x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return project(d).y;
    });
}

map.on("viewreset", render);
map.on("move", render);
map.on("moveend", render);
render(); // Call once to render

</script>
```

### Update

I found this code for reference, linked here at https://data-map-d3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/steps/step_03.html:

```
    function calculateScaleCenter(features) {
  // Get the bounding box of the paths (in pixels!) and calculate a
  // scale factor based on the size of the bounding box and the map
  // size.
  var bbox_path = path.bounds(features),
      scale = 0.95 / Math.max(
        (bbox_path[1][0] - bbox_path[0][0]) / width,
        (bbox_path[1][1] - bbox_path[0][1]) / height
      );

  // Get the bounding box of the features (in map units!) and use it
  // to calculate the center of the features.
  var bbox_feature = d3.geo.bounds(features),
      center = [
        (bbox_feature[1][0] + bbox_feature[0][0]) / 2,
        (bbox_feature[1][1] + bbox_feature[0][1]) / 2];

  return {
    'scale': scale,
    'center': center
  };
}
```

However, when I run the function:

```
  var scaleCenter = calculateScaleCenter(data);
  console.log("scalecenter is", scaleCenter)
```

I get the error:

```
path is not defined
```

Furthermore, it seems like I would need to dynamically adjust the `center` and `zoom` parameters of the mapbox map. Would I just set these values dynamically with the values produced by the `calculateScaleCenter` function?

Comment: Protip: [Never link "here".](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/)

Comment: If you read the code in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/fd3634ff22dc033a) that I referred to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707350/d3-js-proportional-symbol-map-setting-radius-of-a-circle-based-on-data-value), you'll notice that it solves exactly this problem.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, you're exactly right - this worked perfectly.  I deviated a little bit from the observable code and chose lat/lon min and max using a for loop (instead of d3.extent) but it worked as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## The readthedocs example code is erroneously missing a bit of code

Your javascript code is reporting that you have not defined the variable `path` before using it. You have copied it correctly from readthedocs, but the code you are copying contains an omission.

Fortunately, on the readthedocs version of the code snippet, there is a mention of a Stack Overflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067379/841644
that gives more information.

Does adding this information, or something similar corresponding to your situation, help fix your problem?

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

Comment: This is why i'm kind of confused.  The example I'm using doesn't use "path" - it appends a circle based on lat/long.  However, calculateScaleCenter uses path..

Comment: The readthedocs example code _does_ use `path`, on line 39 of the readthedocs example. It's a mistake on the readthedocs website. Fortunately the author gives a link to a StackOverflow page which gives the  code requried.

Comment: Hi, thanks - yes, I'm seeing in the documentation you provided path is used, however, in the d3 code example I posted above (appending circles on a map using d3.js) path is NOT used.  Rather, points are added via a "project" function: map.project(new mapboxgl.LngLat(d[0], d[1]));     Which is why I'm confused.